# Can casting between primitive types cause heap allocations?

Tags: java, jvm

Would the following Java example create heap allocations in any JVM ( `p.position.x` and `p.position.y` are floats ) ?

```
p.position.x = (float)(Math.cos(radians) * 30) + x;
p.position.y = (float)(Math.sin(radians) * 30) + y;
```

And likewise with the following implicit example :

```
float tempX = 0;
float tempY = 0;

tempX += (Math.cos(p.currentOrbitDegrees) * 30) + x;
p.position.x = tempX;

tempY += (Math.sin(p.currentOrbitDegrees) * 30) + y;
p.position.y = tempY;
```

Also, would one method likely be faster than the other across all JVMs?

Comment: "heap allocations" No. "Would one method likely be faster than the other" No. If there was, the compiler would optimize it anyway.

Comment: Something tells me the heap allocation error is coming from somewhere else in your code

Comment: @Michael you should put it as the answer for this question.

Comment: @rabbitguy OP never says that there is an error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

None of the code in your question will cause heap allocation.

In general, the only cases<sup>1</sup> where a conversion *could* result in a heap allocation are boxing and the conversion that can happen with the string concatenation operator (`+`) when one of the operands is not a `String`.

> Also, would one method likely be faster than the other across all JVMs?

No.  That is unlikely.  Across "all" JVMs.

It is plausible that the JIT on some platforms would optimize the redundant initialization and not on other platforms.  Thus the relative performance of the two snippets will be platform dependent.

(In fact it is likely that the difference could be significant for old-enough JVMs; i.e. when JIT compilers were new technology ... or before.)

However:

- The whole question is objectively unanswerable if we consider future versions of Java that haven't been released / prereleased yet.
- You should not be relying on other peoples' gut feeling on this.  Be scientific.  Benchmark your application and run it on multiple platforms.  Then use a profiler to decide if it is worth optimizing this part of your code.

---

But for the example you have provided, the first version is the obvious, simple way to write the code, and should be preferred *for that reason*.

---

<sup>1 - Technically speaking, these conversions are not done by the type-cast itself, but they could potentially happen before or after a widening or narrowing conversion specified by a type-cast.</sup>